# Prolog list recursion, add elements in list

Tags: recursion, prolog

I need to write a recursion in prolog, which adds elements of two lists. Let's say we have a list, `A = [a,b,c]`, and `B = [d,e,f]` and the final list, `R`, should look like this: `R = [a+d, b+e, c+f]`.

I came up only with this:

```
xxx([a], [b], [a+b]).
xxx([H1|T1], [H2|T2], W) :- xxx(T1, T2, W), .(H1+H2, W).
```

But it gives me `uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:5 (char:15) expression or ] expected in list'),read_term/3)`. I also tried this:

```
xxx([a], [b], [a+b]).
xxx([H1|T1], [H2|T2], W) :- xxx(T1, T2, W), append(H1+H2, W, []).
```

With no success: `uncaught exception: error(syntax_error('user_input:4 (char:16) expression or ] expected in list'),read_term/3)`

Im using Gnu prolog (gprolog)

Comment: Note that the dot operator `.` for building lists is usually hidden; you need to do some "trick" to be able to use it. This is probably what is giving the syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
xxx([], [], []).
xxx([E|Es], [F|Fs], [E+F|EFs]) :-
   xxx(E, F, EFs).
```

or

```
..., maplist(ex, Es, Fs, EFs), ...

ex(E, F, E+F).
```

or

```
..., maplist(\E^F^(E+F)^true, Es, Fs, EFs), ...
```

using `library(lambda)`